# Remove before '-' character via Active Directory query

Tags: powershell, active-directory

Input:

```
john.dow-g
stephanie.adam-p
paul.douglas-steve-svr-z
jane.young-ac-a
```

output:

```
-g 
-p
-svr-z
-ac-a
```

My query is fixed but how to make a variable to remove the character before '-' as mention in output above in PowerShell for Active Directory?

```
Get-ADUser -Identity john.dow-g -Server 'domaincontroller.com' -Properties * |
    select {n="suffix";e={$_.SamAccountName.Substring(9)}}
```

Comment: How should the code know that the suffix for `paul.douglas-steve-svr-z` should be `-svr-z` and not `-steve-svr-z`?

Comment: Have a look at PowerShell [split](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2014/07/17/using-the-split-method-in-powershell/) function.

Comment: are these suffixes stored in a know location that you could also query?

Comment: Unless ac & svr (or svr-z & ac-a) are known "extra" suffixes there is no clear common logic to programmatically split these names and suffixes

Answer (score 0):

```
get-aduser -identity john.dow-g -server 'domaincontroller.com' -properties *| 
    Foreach-object{ 
       $Array = ($_.split('-'))
       '-' + (($Array[1..($Array.count-1)]) -join '-')

    }
```

You will keep having trouble with your 3the example.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing information on the question, you either have a template to compare on, Ie. @('-ABC-A',-abc-a), or you check for example the last 2 '-' and the contents in between.

I'll expand on the second:

Pipeline:

```
'paul.douglas-steve-svr-z' | % {$_.Substring($_.Substring(0,$_.LastIndexOf('-')).lastIndexOf('-'),$_.Length-($_.Substring(0,$_.LastIndexOf('-')).lastIndexOf('-')))}
```

As you can see that kind of a handful and in can be expanded to as much quantity of '-' as possible.

Better way (IMO):

```
$text='paul.douglas-steve-svr-z'

if($text.Split('-').Count -ge 3){

    $lastSymbolPosition = $text.LastIndexOf('-')
    $secondLastSymbilPosition = $text.Substring(0,$lastSymbolPosition).LastIndexOf('-')
    $prefix=$text.Substring($secondLastSymbilPosition,$text.Length-$secondLastSymbilPosition)

    $prefix

}else{

    'Out of the solution scope'

}
```

Although I cannot give you a definitive answer because I don't know the objective of this text processing.

Hope this helps.